# Conditional breakpoint not honored

Tags: pydev

I have the following snippet in a method.

```
cnt = chunk.count('abc')
x = 1
```

I set a conditional breakpoint on the second statement with the condition `cnt > 0`. However, the breakpoint happens when the value of `cnt` is zero. How do I get the breakpoint to happen only when `cnt > 0`?

The code is in a multiprocessing process.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/895

I hope to have this fixed for PyDev 6.3.3.